# Can I pass a jmockit mock of an interface as a constructor parameter of another object?

Tags: java, android, tdd, jmockit

i'm playing around with jmockit. Most of what I tried(with the help of the web) works splendid.

But it seems, like there is a problem when passing a reference to a

```
@Mocked
SomeInterface someInterface
```

as a parameter to a constructor of object under test. The test run shows, that the instance is null.

Any ideas?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@Capturing` instead of `@Mocked`.

`@Mocked` only mocks all instances of the given class and its super-classes but not the sub-classes or implementations of interfaces. That's what `@Capturing` is for. (see [Capturing implementation classes and instances](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#capturing))